# Adding Objects into Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I have a class of credit card account information. The information is being read in from the file and needs to be stored into an array. So far the class is as defined:

```
    private CreditCardAccount[] accountsArray;
    private int fillLevel;
    
    public SortedArray() {
        accountsArray = new CreditCardAccount[1000];
    }
    
    private class CreditCardAccount{
        
        long accountNum;
        String name;
        String address;
        double creditLimit;
        double balance;
        
        CreditCardAccount (long accountNum, String name, String address, double crerditLimit, double balance) {
            
            this.accountNum = accountNum;
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;
            this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
            this.balance = balance;
            
        }
        
    }
```

I am trying to insert the objects to an array but when I print out index 0 for example it keeps printing out the first credit card number repeatedly. Or when I try to print out index 1, it says the credit card number is null. I have tried this to insert:

```
private static void insert(SortedArray.CreditCardAccount[] accounts, CreditCardAccount account, int fillLevel) {
        
        for(int i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
            
            if(accounts[i] == null) {
                
                accounts[i] = account;
                
                System.out.println(accounts[i].name);
                
                break;
                
                
            } 
        }
    }
```

This part is from where I am reading in and calling createAccount

```
operation = opsFile.nextLine();
    long acocuntNum = Long.parseLong(operation);
                    
    operation = opsFile.nextLine();
    String name = operation;
                    
    operation = opsFile.nextLine();
    String address = operation;
                    
    operation = opsFile.nextLine();
    double creditLimit = Double.parseDouble(operation);
                    
    operation = opsFile.nextLine();
    double balance = Double.parseDouble(operation);
                    
    database.createAccount(acocuntNum, name, address, creditLimit, balance);
```

This is where insert is getting called:

```
public boolean createAccount(long accountNumber, String name, String address, double creditLimit, double balance) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        boolean accountCreated = true;
        
        
        CreditCardAccount newAccount = new CreditCardAccount(accountNumber, name, address, creditLimit, balance);
        
        SortedArray.insert(accountsArray, newAccount, fillLevel);
        
        return accountCreated;
    }
```

I think it is adding the first object to every index in the array. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Comment: Please add the code where your read the credit card information from the file and where you call the function ```insert```

Comment: edited it to add where information is being read and where insert is being called

Comment: where do you initialize ```accountsArray``` ? You probably  have a loop around your third code block. You have to initialize ```accountsArray```  outside of this loop.

Comment: accountsArray is being initialized in the class field at the top of my class

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the break and the if statement. You're breaking out of the loop after the first iteration, sou you dont insert anything in accounts [1]. Also the if statement says after the first iteration dont add anything anymore, because the first index is not null. Thats why you keep getting the first account back.

Comment: i've tried that but it would duplicate each account number 15 times